# Website mobile switchers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mobile

Not long ago I got my hands on a website, which I played with a bit. Mostly trying to implement a mobile switcher from mobile view to desktop view and vice versa.

I came accross some really "fancy" javascript switchers, that did the job, but i could say it was buggy.
I coded a rather simply switcher in JS a while ago, which worked fine, but was waaaay too simple from the one that was "fancy".

Not long ago I managed to code a yet simple switcher in PHP.
And i havent stumbled upon a lot of PHP mobile switchers.
Was just wondering whats the difference between a very fancy one and a simple one, and between javasctipt switchers and PHP. Which one is better?( in one way or another)

(Worth mentioning that at the end everything modified viewport tag)

and that I took PHP and JS rather in an amateur way (never had it professionally taught) so I might be missing a lot of things here and there.

Comment: [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) have made switching from one version to another largely obsolete.

Comment: Well, either way they are the "essentials" to a responsive design.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean. Responsive Web Design is defined as combining Flexible Grid Layout (currently implemented with Flexbox), flexible images (by using relative scaling units) and CSS Media Queries. Using JavaScript to switch from one version of a site to another is not part of that modern methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I didnt get much help here, I figured out myself that a php mobile switcher seems more efficient than one written in js.
Basically as far as I checked, it would be better if everything was done on server side, rather than have the visitor do it. This ofc increases the work server has to do, but I believe is too small to be taken into consideration.